# Why am I not able to install PyInstaller? What does this error mean?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to install `PyInstaller` and I keep getting this error when I try to use `pip`. I am running Linux Mint 19.1.

```
elijah@elijah-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cMtlUT/pyinstaller/
elijah@elijah-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$
```

Comment: what python version are you using? Perhaps               sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools                      will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have setuptools yet. You can try to install it first.

```
pip install setuptools
```

Or this one for your linux.

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```